# Get value from "Var" variable 

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, select

I'm trying to get a row from my SQL Server database. I don't know how to get it I tried many ways but I coludn't get any good solution.

```
databasEntities db = new databasEntities();
var medlem = from medlemar in db.medlemar
             where medlemar.namn == "Ali"
             select medlemar;
```

Here is my database table `Medlemar`:

- id
- namn
- losen
- epost

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Do you got any errors? post it please.

Comment: What does your current code return? What do you want it to return?

Comment: The problem is that i want to get the value i have in the database, like i want the data who is in the column "losen" in the table "medlemar". When i write it like that Label1.Text = medlem.ToString(); i get this on the page  System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[WebApplication2.medlemar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

medlem will be a collection of objects so you should be able to use foreach or .first on that.

```
foreach(var m in medlem)
{
     var namn = m.namm;
     ...
}
```

or

```
 var m1 = medlem.First();
```

Answer (score 5):

In C#, `var` is not a typeless type.  It is actually a way of implicitly typing objects without having to type out the entire type name.

For example:

```
var someString = "Any String Value";
```

and

```
string someString = "Any String Value";
```

compile to exactly the same IL.

So in your case, the LINQ is returning an `IEnumerable<T>` collection, where T is the type of your `medlemar` object.

Since it is a collection, you need to access it just as you would any other collection.  One possibility is using `foreach`

```
foreach(var m in medlem)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Another possibility is calling `ToList()` and then accessing individual members by index:

```
var medlemList =  medlem.ToList();
var namn = medlemList[i].namn;   // where i is some specific index in the collection
```

Or if you just want to get the first object in the collection, you have several alternatives depending on your use case:

```
var firstMedlem = medlem.Single();
var firstMedlem = medlem.First();
var firstMedlem = medlem.SingleOrDefault();
var firstMedlem = medlem.FirstOrDefault();
```

Each of the above do roughly the same thing but will behave differently if the collection has zero or multiple objects.

`Single()` will return the only object in a collection.  If the collection contains multiple objects or zero, an exception will be thrown.  Similarly, `SingleOrDefault()` will throw an exception if there are multiple objects, but will return the value returned by `default(T)` (usually null, except for when T is a value type).

`First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` also behave the same way where `First()` will throw an exception if the collection is empty and `FirstOrDefault()` will return the default value.  They are different from the `Single..()` methods in that they will always return the first member if a collection has multiple values.

So basically, `FirstOrDefault()` will never throw an exception unless the collection itself is null.  The other variations will throw an exception in one or more cases depending on the contents of the `IEnumerable<T>` collection.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) something like:

```
   var medlem = from medlemar in db.medlemar
                           where medlemar.namn == "Ali"
                           select medlemar;
   string nameFromVar = medlem.FirstOrDefault();
```

There are other options you can use besides `FirstOrDefault()`:

- [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) returns a single item like `FirstOrDefault()` but it will throw an exception if there is either none or more than one item.
- [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) also returns a single item, but throw when there is no item.

But in case of the `FirstOrDefault()` it will return the first item or return null when there is no item or more accurate:

> default(TSource) if source is empty; otherwise, the first element in
>   source.